WindowsCommunityToolKit: Stretch SettingsCard to window size (vertical and horizontal)
If I do something like this
<Grid>
    <controls:SettingsCard 
                         ContentAlignement="Left">
        <TextBox/>
    </controls:SettingsCard>
</Grid>

The SettingsCard will stretch width to window size but not height.
Is it possible to stretch the SettingsCard also in vertical way to window size?
I would like to include a datagrid in the settings card where the datagrid scrollbar appears when the windowsize is reached.
Currently the settings card expands "infinitely" depending on the content of the datagrid and thus goes out of range. As a result, no scrollbar appears in the datagrid itself, of course
I hope my question/requirement is understandable

The SettingsCard control has a Grid as a root which contains a ContentPresenter named PART_ContentPresenter on its second Row.
In order to place this ContentPresenter on the top, you need to change the Grid.Row to 0 and Grid.RowSpan to 2.
The following code on the Loaded event should work:
private void SettingsCard_Loaded(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not SettingsCard settingsCard)
    {
        return;
    }

    settingsCard.ContentAlignment = ContentAlignment.Left;

    if (settingsCard.FindDescendants()
        .OfType<ContentPresenter>()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "PART_ContentPresenter") is not { } contentPresenter)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Forces the ControlPresenter to stay on Row 0.
    _ = contentPresenter.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(
        Grid.RowProperty,
        (_, _) =>
        {
            Grid.SetRow(contentPresenter, 0);
        });

    Grid.SetRow(contentPresenter, 0);
    Grid.SetRowSpan(contentPresenter, 2);
    contentPresenter.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
}

